# Appending element clone to svg group in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am able to append a rectangle to group on drag drop but it is not working properly. If I drag and drop multiple rectangles on to group, the rectangles are dislocated at different location. I am sure there must be some thing wrong.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wqvLLbLa/

code:

```
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                        .attr("width", 800)
                        .attr("height", 803);

                var rect = svgContainer.append("rect")
                        .attr("x", 10)
                        .attr("y", 50)
                        .attr("width", 51)
                        .attr("height", 41)
                        .attr("rx", 10)
                        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                        .attr("stroke", "#7E7E7E")
                        .style('cursor', 'move')
                        .style("fill", "white");

                function moveRect() {
                    d3.select(this)
                            .attr('x', d3.event.x)
                            .attr('y', d3.event.y);
                }

                var dragGroup = d3.behavior.drag()
                        .origin(function () {
                            var g = this;
                            return {x: d3.transform(g.getAttribute("transform")).translate[0],
                                    y: d3.transform(g.getAttribute("transform")).translate[1]};
                        })
                        .on("drag", function (d, i) {
                            g = this;
                            translate = d3.transform(g.getAttribute("transform")).translate;
                            console.log(translate);
                            x = d3.event.dx + translate[0],
                            y = d3.event.dy + translate[1];
                            d3.select(g).attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
                            d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
                        });

                var group = svgContainer.append("g")
                        .attr("id", "mygroup")
                        .call(dragGroup)
                        .style('cursor', 'move')
                        .attr("transform", "translate(20, 20)");

                group.append("rect")
                        .attr("x", 250)
                        .attr("y", 250)
                        .attr("width", 151)
                        .attr("height", 141)
                        .attr("rx", 10)
                        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                        .attr("stroke", "#7E7E7E")
                        .style("fill", "white");

                var circleDrag = d3.behavior.drag()
                        .origin(function ()
                        {
                            var t = d3.select(this);
                            return {x: t.attr("cx"), y: t.attr("cy")};
                        })

                var rectDrag = d3.behavior.drag()
                        .origin(function ()
                        {
                            var t = d3.select(this);
                            return {x: t.attr("x"), y: t.attr("y")};
                        })

                        .on('dragend', function (d) {
                            var mouseCoordinates = d3.mouse(this);
                            var groupTransform = d3.transform(group.attr("transform"));
                            var groupX = groupTransform.translate[0];
                            var groupY = groupTransform.translate[1];
                            var rect = group.select("rect");
                            var rectX = +rect.attr("x");
                            var rectY = +rect.attr("y");
                            var rectWidth = +rect.attr("width");
                            var rectHeight = +rect.attr("height");

                            if (mouseCoordinates[0] > groupX + rectX
                                    && mouseCoordinates[0] < groupX + rectX + rectWidth
                                    && mouseCoordinates[1] > groupY + rectY
                                    && mouseCoordinates[1] < groupY + rectY + rectHeight) {

                                //Append new element
                                var newRect = d3.select("g").append("rect")
                                        .classed("drg", true)
                                        .attr("x", 100)
                                        .attr("y", 100)
                                        .attr("rx", 10)
                                        .attr("width", 51)
                                        .attr("height", 41)
                                        .attr("x", mouseCoordinates[0])
                                        .attr("y", mouseCoordinates[1])
                                        .style("fill", "white")
                                        .style("stroke-width", 2)
                                        .style("stroke", "#CDB483");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var newRect = d3.select("svg").append("rect")
                                        .classed("drg", true)
                                        .attr("x", 100)
                                        .attr("y", 100)
                                        .attr("rx", 10)
                                        .attr("width", 51)
                                        .attr("height", 41)
                                        .attr("x", mouseCoordinates[0])
                                        .attr("y", mouseCoordinates[1])
                                        .style("fill", "white")
                                        .style("stroke-width", 2)
                                        .style("stroke", "#CDB483")
                                        .call(
                                                d3.behavior.drag()
                                                .on('drag', moveRect).origin(function () {
                                            var t = d3.select(this);
                                            return {x: t.attr("x"), y: t.attr("y")};
                                        }));
                            }
                        });
                rect.call(rectDrag);
```

Comment: did you get this sorted out?

Comment: No I am working on this from past three weeks. Some or the other issue in the program. Will post the updated fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y05p7rz6/ Please have a look if you get time. Drag and drop into group is creating two circles instead of one

Comment: er... is this the fiddle for this question or the other question's comment?

Comment: Both question are same. This is the updated fiddle

Comment: Think I'm missing something. There are as many circle svg elements as there are visible circles (no extras) - the only this is they are not getting appended to the group - your latest question has the answer for that. I am using IE11 btw. Cheers!

Comment: @potatopeelings Please have a look in chrome or firefox. I am not worried about IE compatability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Responding to the update question - as in the comments.

The reason for the duplicates is because you are appending a new element to the targetG after your bounds check, instead of targetCircle.

The easiest way to fix this would be to simply remove targetCircle after appending the new circle like so

```
targetCircle.remove();
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/afmLhofL/

Comment: @kittu - by the way, you might want to update the question with the description and fiddle from your comments. As is, the question is totally different :-)

Comment: This would work, but just thinking appending targetCircle instead of new element possible would be a easy fix? may be that would be ideal...just let know me..I will try that out later. By the way, thanks a lot for this fix :)